# Is it possible to construct anonymous/delegates like the following in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, anonymous-function

Is there anyway to accomplish the following? Here is some simplified semi pseudo code of what I am trying to do:

```
class Foo {

  static public FUNCTION one(int foo, int bar) {    
    return List<Vector> FUNCTION(int num)  {      
      List<Vector> v = new List<Vector>();
      for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        v.Add( new Vector(1+foo, 1+bar) );      
      }
      return v;
    }

  static public FUNCTION two(int foo, int bar) {    
    return List<Vector> FUNCTION(int num)  {      
      List<Vector> v = new List<Vector>();
      // Do something else?
      return v;
    }

  }    
}
```

Then I would like to call it like so:

```
 generic = Foo.one(1, 2);
 List<Vector> v = generic(2);

 generic = Foo.two(1, 2);
 List<Vector> v = generic(2);
```

I think this is kind of along the lines of what I want but I'm unsure how to pass the first set of arguments in.

```
public static Func<int, int, List<Vector>> one()
{
    Func<int, List<Vector>> func = (int num) =>
    {
      List<Vector> v = new List<Vector>();
      return v;
    };
    return func;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that a solution for your problem? It is a construct called `Closure`. It is just a combination of what you already had.

```
public static Func<int, List<Vector>> one(int foo, int bar)
{
    Func<int, List<Vector>> func =
        num =>
        {
            List<Vector> v = new List<Vector>();
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                v.Add(new Vector(1 + foo, 1 + bar));
            }
            return v;
        };

    return func;
}
```

Comment: I believe this was exactly what I was trying to do. I do have one question though. Do both Func signatures have to match? Can you do something like:
public static Func<int, List<Vector>> one(int foo, int bar)
{
 Func<int, int, List<Vector>> func = (num, num2) => {};
  return func;
}

Comment: Of course not. The type of the returned object has to be the same (or a derived one) as what is defined in the function signature. You also can't return an integer from a function which expects a string return value. If you want to return an `Func<int, int, List<Vector>>` object just define it in the return signature of your `one` function.